# Hide/Show class with css when component is loaded

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have two modals inside of my app. One is a Survey modal - the other, is a TimeOutModal component that prompts a logout "Yes or No" button asking if the user needs more time signed in.

The Survey is called via an embedded javascript snippet on page load that renders a class, while the TimeOutModal is its own component that renders after 5 mins of inactivity.

Both are popups that take over the whole page.

My issue is, when the TimeOutModal appears, I need to be able to completely hide the Survey if it is still visible on-screen. If the user chooses "Yes" to stay lagged in, the TimeOutModal should disappear and unhide the Survey modal.

I'm not sure how to specify a class inside of my TimeOutModal component that will effect the Survey via a hide/show state.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my TimeOutModal code:

```
export default class TimeoutModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if (!isUndefined(props.timeoutObject)) {
            props.timeoutObject.endTimeoutTimer();
        }

        var timeRemaining = props.duration * 1000 || 5 * 60 * 1000;
        // Create a global reference to the end time, rather than a countdown.
        this.endTime = new Date().getTime() + timeRemaining;

        // Update the timer ever second
        setInterval(this.updateTimer, 1000);
        this.timeoutObject = setTimeout(this.logout, timeRemaining);

        this.state = {
            timeRemaining: timeRemaining - 1000,
        };
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    };

    logout = () => {
        return (window.location = this.props.endUrl);
    };

    updateTimer = () => {
        this.setState(() => {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var timeRemaining = this.endTime - now;
            if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
                this.logout();
            }
            return {
                timeRemaining: timeRemaining,
            };
        });
    };

    continueSelected = () => {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutObject);
        this.props.continueFunction();
    };

    formatTime = () => {
        const distance = this.state.timeRemaining;
        const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
            return '0:00';
        }
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
        return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    };
```

Comment: Is this a react application? Do you need to strictly use CSS? If your using react IMO you should use state to specify which modal is showing and which is not.

Comment: Can you show the code of your modals?

Comment: @JoseA.Ayllón I've updated my question with some code. There is quite a bit more in the render method. The Survey modal is generated by javascript snippet that is hosted on a secure server. I don't want to post that here.

Comment: @per.eight It is a React app. Only one modal is its own component, the other is a js snippet that is called on browser load. Using state is preferable as well, I'm struggling to find a solution.

Comment: @dooge showing code of the modal really help us check how it was setup so we can help you in details.